# Loop to find label, then change text

Tags: jquery, replace, label

I have the following markup being generated by a CMS:

```
<div class="product">
<div class="blk">
  <span>
    <br>
    <label>Size</label>
    <select onchange="" name="">
  </span>
  <span>
    <br>
    <label>Colour</label>
    <select onchange="" name="">
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to replace the label text whenever 'Size' is present. I have tried a variety of code... such as:

```
$('.productOptionsBlock .blk span label').each(function() {
    if ($(this).('label:contains("Size")').length > 0) {
        $(this).replaceWith('<span>Alternative text</span>');
    }
});
```

But I can't get the replacement to work. I get confused with using `$(this)` and how to attach the label contents...

Comment: Sorry yes - changed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to loop for this task, you just apply the same thing to the selector:

```
$('.productOptionsBlock .blk span label:contains("Size")').replaceWith('<span>Alternative text</span>');
```

[**Check a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/yPPY3/)

Comment: In newer browsers it's faster (and nicer to read!) to simply use `label:contains("Size")` as the selector.  [Demo](http://jsperf.com/townselectortest1)

Comment: @Town: Definitely, however there might be some other label on the DOM which contains `Size`, thus it might help to limit its context. On the other hand, I haven't banchmarked, but I believe `.blk > span > label:contains("Size")` would be faster, and with a limit to the context.

Comment: Good point, very true.  I've added that descendants test (with and without context) into the [jsperf demo](http://jsperf.com/townselectortest1).  The straight `label:contains("Size")` is still fastest, however I would imagine that the descendants test would perform significantly faster in older browsers.

Comment: @Town: [Looks like I was wrong](http://jsperf.com/ancestor-descendant-vs-direct-child-jquery-selectors), at least for the latest browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).('label:contains("Size")')` doesn't do anything.

Perhaps you meant:

```
if ($(this).is('label:contains("Size")')) {
```

---

You don't need the explicit loop, though:

```
$('.productOptionsBlock .blk span label:contains("Size")')
   .replaceWith('<span>Alternative text</span>');
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak - you must have been seconds behind Shef :)

Comment: @AndyiBM: About ten minutes actually. It's not a race!